# Tailwindcss use hover over group-hover is not working

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Tailwindcss use hover over group-hover is not working

I don't know why it's not working. I think this code is correct. But it is not change color. Always show black color.

```
<div className="flex items-center md:px-10 sm:h-14 md:hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl active:border-b-2 active:border-blue-500">
    <Icon className="h-5 text-center sm:h-7 group-hover:text-blue-500" />
</div>
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}','./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      divideColor: ['group-hover'],
      backgroundColor: ['group-focus'],
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to give your parent element the class `group` for it to work.

Try this:

```html
<div className="group flex items-center md:px-10 sm:h-14 md:hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl active:border-b-2 active:border-blue-500">
    <Icon className="h-5 text-center sm:h-7 group-hover:text-blue-500" />
</div>
```